# Индикаторы загрузки

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-ui, loading

## Описание

Мне нужно между переходами сцен сделать панель загрузки. Было бы ещё лучше увидеть там процент загрузки или хотя бы полоску показывающий - сколько осталось.

## Вопрос

*Каким создать этот панель, чтобы было не только приятно пользователю, но и ещё удобно для меня?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Внешний вид

Для начала создаём внешний вид этой панели. Пусть макет будет таким:

[image]

Потом доделаем внешний вид:

[image]

Уже лучше!

---

## Скрипт

Создаём скрипт и прикрепляем на панели загрузки. Первое что делаем - переход по сценам.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Loading : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int SceneId; //Id сцены которая будет загружена

    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(LoadingFunction()); //При включении запускаем загрузку
    }

    IEnumerator LoadingFunction() //Создаём функцию загрузки используя новый поток
    {
        SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(SceneId);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Теперь чтобы управлять процентами и.т.д. пишем:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Loading : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int SceneId;
    private readonly string[] Hints = new string[] //Подсказки во время загрузки
    {
        "Ваша жизнь длится дольше, когда вы дышите.",
        "Почти всегда в третьем этаже пол ниже потолка.",
        "Если мужчине зовут Наташа, то это женщина!",
    };
    public Text ProgressText, HintText;
    public Image ProgressImage;

    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(LoadingFunction());
        HintText.text = Hints[Random.Range(0, Hints.Length)]; //Показываем случайную подсказку
    }

    IEnumerator LoadingFunction()
    {
        AsyncOperation Operation = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(SceneId);
        while (!Operation.isDone)
        {
            float Progress = Operation.progress;
            ProgressText.text = $"{( Progress * 100 ).ToString("0")}%"; //Процент загрузки
            ProgressImage.fillAmount = Progress;
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь нам надо только отключить этот объект в инспекторе и сделать из него Prefab. Чтобы начать загрузку меняем `SceneId` и включаем его.

---

## Работоспособность

[image]